# Result of MOV CX, DAT[4] indexing into array of words (DW)

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I have the following commands

```
DAT DW 128,256,64,32
MOV CX, DAT[4]
```

As I know, DAT[4] means we will get value of 4th index, but in this case we don't have such an index.
Could you please tell me what I will have in the `CX` register after `MOV CX, DAT[4]` ?

Comment: Indexing normally uses bytes, but that does depend on your assembler. If the question is asked like this, we can assume bytes so that loads the `64` each word being 2 bytes.

Comment: You could put this into a program and assemble it to see what machine code you get, and even run it and use a debugger to look at register values.  You don't need to ask other people when you can just try it on a real machine.

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: I'm using Turbo Assember

Comment: Friends, after DAT DW 128,256,64,32 DAT will look like 0000 0000 1000 0000 / 0000 0001 0000 0000 / 0000 0000 0100 0000 / 0000 0000 0010 0000, am I correct ?

Comment: x86 is little endian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I know, DAT[4] means we will get value of 4th index,

In assembly language we don't use array indexing based on whole elements like in the high level languages. In a high level language `DAT[4]` would retrieve the fifth array element (if indexing started at 0).

In assembly language the number between the square brackets is an offset from the start of the array and measured in bytes.
Your example:

```
DAT DW 128,256,64,32
```

rewritten using hex:

```
DAT DW 0080h, 0100h, 0040h, 0020h
```

presents itself in memory like (x86 being little endian):

```
80h, 00h, 00h, 01h, 40h, 00h, 20h, 00h
^                   ^
offset 0            offset 4
```

The word at offset 4 contains a low byte of 40h and a high byte of 00h.
Therefore `MOV CX, DAT[4]` will load `CX` with 0040h which is 64 in decimal.

Comment: Finally, I got it))

Comment: @VaruzhanStepanyan Once you get these basic things thoroughly explained, you're on your way to a good understanding of the assembly language. Happy learning...